# Within a Spring batch processor, how to commit entity to Database immediately on calling repository.save()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am creating a Spring Batch process (Spring Boot 2) that reads a file and writes it to a Database. It processes it one record at a time. Read from file, process it, and write (or update) to the Database.
If a record for the same ID exists in the DB, the process has to update the end date of the existing record in DB, and create a new record with new start date. Below is the code:

```
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<CelebVO, CelebVO> {
@Autowired
EndorseTableRepository endorseTableRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public CelebVO process(CelebVO celebVO) {
        CelebEndorsement celebEndorsement = endorseTableRepository.findAllByCelebIDAndBrandID(celebVO.getCelebID(),celebVO.getBrandID());
        if (celebEndorsement == null) {
            CelebEndorsement newEndorsement = new CelebEndorsement(celebVO);
            endorseTableRepository.save(newEndorsement);
        } else {
            celebEndorsement.setEndDate(celebVO.getEffDt.minusDays(1));
            endorseTableRepository.save(celebEndorsement);
            // create a new row with new start date
            CelebEndorsement newEndorsement = new CelebEndorsement(celebVO);
            newEndorsement.setStartDate(celebVO.getEffDt());
            endorseTableRepository.save(newEndorsement);
        }
    
    return celebVO;
}
```

}

Below is the input txt file (CelebVO):

```
CelebID     BrandID     EffDt
J Lo        Pepsi       2021-01-05
J Lo        Pepsi       2021-05-30
```

Now, lets suppose we are starting with an empty EndorseTable. When the process picks up the file and reads the records, it will see there are no records for CelebID 'J Lo'. So it will insert a row to the DB.
Now, the process reads the second row and process it. It should see that there is already a record in the table for J Lo. So it should put an endDate to that records and then create a new record.

After this file is processed we should see two records in the table.

But that is not what is happening. Though I do a repository.save() for the first record, it is still not commited to the table. So when the process reads the second row, it doesn't find any rows in the table. It ends up writing only one record to the table.

I tried a repository.saveAndFlush(). That doesn't help.
My chunk size is 1

I tried removing @Transactional. But that breaks the code. So I kept it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify the Entity class. I replaced

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

with

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The [chunk-oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) of Spring Batch commits a transaction per chunk, not per record. So in your case, if the insert and the update happen to be in the same chunk, the processor won't see the change of the previous record as the transaction is not committed yet at that point.

Adding `@Transactional` on your processor's method is incorrect, because the processor will already be executed within the scope of a transaction driven by Spring Batch. What you are trying to do would work if you set the commit interval to 1, but this would impact the performance of your step.